# Match string with `char::is_ascii_alphanumeric` fails, whereas `char::is_alphanumeric` compiles

Tags: string, rust, ascii

I want to match only alphanumeric ascii characters of a string, but the `matches` function only only works with `is_alphanumeric`. The following example should clarify. I also put it on [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=89db7ae1eda9cb48d32bd29a2f1002bf), for easy reproducibility.

```rust
fn main() {
    "s".matches(char::is_alphanumeric).collect(); // Works
    "s".matches(char::is_ascii_alphanumeric).collect(); // Doesn't work
}
```

Two errors are produced, the second depends on the first, I think. The error message states:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     "s".matches(char::is_ascii_alphanumeric).collect(); // Doesn't work
  |         ^^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         expected signature of `fn(char) -> _`
  |         found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> _`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::str::pattern::Pattern<'_>` for `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> bool {std::char::methods::<impl char>::is_ascii_alphanumeric}`

error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `std::str::Matches<'_, for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> bool {std::char::methods::<impl char>::is_ascii_alphanumeric}>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:3:46
  |
3 |     "s".matches(char::is_ascii_alphanumeric).collect(); // Doesn't work
  |                                              ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `&mut std::str::Matches<'_, for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> bool {std::char::methods::<impl char>::is_ascii_alphanumeric}> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `std::str::Matches<'_, for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> bool {std::char::methods::<impl char>::is_ascii_alphanumeric}> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Can anyone explain to me, what this error means and why it works for one function but not the other? I looked at the type signature of both functions, but they look the same to me:

- [is_alphanumeric](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_alphanumeric)
- [is_ascii_alphanumeric](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_ascii_alphanumeric)

I use Rust v1.37.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why it works for one function but not the other?

Let's take a look at the signatures:

```rust
fn       is_alphanumeric( self) -> bool
fn is_ascii_alphanumeric(&self) -> bool
```

One function takes `&self` (a reference) and the other takes `self` (by value) as argument. This is an important difference in this case. Now let's check the error again:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in function arguments
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     "s".matches(char::is_ascii_alphanumeric).collect(); // Doesn't work
  |         ^^^^^^^
  |         |
  |         expected signature of `fn(char) -> _`
  |         found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> _`
```

Especially the last part (aligned by me):

```
  |         expected signature of `        fn(    char) -> _`
  |         found signature of    `for<'r> fn(&'r char) -> _`
```

It shows that a function taking `char` as argument is expected, but a function taking `&'r char` as argument was found. Ignore the `for<'r>` and `'r` here, they are not important in this case.

Why is `fn(char)` expected? Well, looking at [`str::matches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) it shows that it accepts anything that implements [`Pattern`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/pattern/trait.Pattern.html). Among the implementors of `Pattern`, we find:

```rust
impl<'a, F> Pattern<'a> for F
where
    F: FnMut(char) -> bool,
```

And that's the reason why a function taking `char` by value and *not* by reference was expected.

How can you fix it? You can always provide a closure and just call the method with the value referenced. This is likely to not have any runtime overhead as the closure can easily be inlined by the optimizer.

```rust
"s".matches(|c| char::is_ascii_alphanumeric(&c))
```

---

A few additional things:

- The second error message is just a result of the first. It goes away after applying the fix.
- You still need to specify the type of the collection you want to collect the iterator into. For example `Vec<_>`:

  ```rust
  let x: Vec<_> = "s".matches(|c| char::is_ascii_alphanumeric(&c)).collect();
  ```
- Why do these two methods of `char` have different signatures?! This seems strange, and indeed taking `self` by value would be preferred for both. Coincidentally, I was the one who added `is_ascii_alphanumeric` to `char` directly in [this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44042). This in inconsistency was [brought up](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44042#issuecomment-370365365) and I explained the reason for this strangeness [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/44042#issuecomment-370399951).

  The reason is simply that the method was just moved from an old `AsciiExt` trait. This trait is deprecated now. Sadly, the method in question was already stabilized as taking `&self`. Moving the method to `char` is fine, but adding the signature would break code. So the `&self` signature was kept. Short answer: **backwards compatibility**. I also found [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57307) where someone tried almost the same as you did.